# Wordpress/PHP function w/nested conditional?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, conditional-statements

In Short: I am creating a WP function that will echo a image url based on the following conditions

in english here's how the conditional should work

1. if custom taxonomy terms exist then build the img src url from custom taxonomy terms
2. elseif custom taxonomy does not exist - then display default image
3. else custom taxonomy exists but the image is not avail. in external url then display default image

here's what I've got so far, **I cant get step 3 to work**

I did find this solution:

```
function is_200(){

$urlimage = 'http://images.mysite.com/auto/mercedes-car.jpg';
if(@getimagesize($urlimage) !== false)
{
    echo "HAVE image";
}
else
{
    echo "Nop.";
}
}
```

but I couldent get it to work with my function, below

```
function cib_auto_thumbnail($width,$height) {
  $timurl = "http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/timthumb.php?src="; 

  $thumburl ="http://images.mywebsite.com/auto/"; 
  $defaultthumb ="http://images.mywebsite.com/auto/cib.jpg"; 
  $thumburl2 =".jpg"; 

  $timmake =""; $i = 1; foreach((get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'OriginalTag' )) as $timmakecat) {if ($timmakecat->parent == 0) {$timmake .= $timmakecat->name; if($i == 1) break;}} ;
  $timmodel =""; $i = 1; foreach((get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'OriginalTag' )) as $timmodelcat) {if ($timmodelcat->parent |= 0) {$timmodel .= $timmodelcat->name; if($i == 1) break;}} ;

 if (empty($timmake) || empty($timmodel)) {

    echo '<img src="' . $timurl . $defaultthumb .'" / >'; 

    // if no make or model i.e. custom taxonomy is blank; then get default image 
// problem is a custom taxonomy can be created by the author - but the corrosponding image might not exist in the external file folder, hence I need the additional elseif to check for that 

  }   else {

echo '<img src="' . $timurl . $thumburl . $timmake . '-' . $timmodel . $thumburl2 .'" / >';

    // else get image from make and model custom taxonomy and create image url 

 }
```

**OriginalTags is the name of my custom taxonomy terms

*** Every image in the external location is named appropriately as: make-model.jpg i.e. $timmake-$timmodel.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name') );
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array('taxonomy'=>'features', 'image_size' => 'details', 'term_args' => 'hide_empty=0', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'orderby' => 'title', 'count'   => 2) ); 
foreach($terms as $term){

   echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $term, $term->taxonomy ) ) . '">' . wp_get_attachment_image( $term->image_id, 'thumb' )  . '</a>';
?>
```

Comment: Maulik, can you please elaborate - I'm a little lost as to where I'm putting this